# csv file with Japanese Kanji character is not importing in mysql database

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was trying to design a user database in MySQL. In one field, there requires storing Japanese character name (Kanji). I used the below format while creating user_name field in the table
`user_name  varchar(250)    sjis_japanese_ci`

While importing the csv, I used the character set SJIS instead of Unicode (utf-8). But it is giving the below error:

```
Notice in ./libraries/classes/Encoding.php#180
 iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

Backtrace
./libraries/classes/Encoding.php#180: iconv(
string 'SJIS',
string 'utf-8//TRANSLIT',
string ,
)
./libraries/classes/Import.php#394: PhpMyAdmin\Encoding::convertString(
string 'SJIS',
string 'utf-8',
string ,
)
./libraries/classes/Plugins/Import/ImportCsv.php#245: PhpMyAdmin\Import::getNextChunk()
./import.php#554: PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Import\ImportCsv->doImport(array)
```

Can anyone please help what went wrong?

Comment: Import your CSV using MySQL, by LOAD DATA query (with correct charset/collation options), do not use PHP statements for this purposes.

Comment: As someone who works with Japanese text all day, do yourself a favour and use UTF-8 everywhere if at all possible. The Japanese-specific encodings add zero value and only make every far more difficult than necessary later on ...